# Why is Buzz the only toy that does not believe he is a toy?

Tags: character, toy-story

In [Toy Story](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toy_Story), Why is Buzz the only toy that does not believe he is a toy?
Is this a stage of being a toy or does Buzz have some sort of neurological dysfunction?

Comment: I don't know if the writers thought about it that much. It's a great question. Do they dream? Do they feel the same way we do? Is it just magic? Are they immortal? Where do they go when they die?

Comment: @BamfTheNightAway Yeah, you have to wonder how Buzz felt the first time Andy played with him. Some giant, humanoid child tossing you around...

Comment: And [this question](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/3012/why-does-buzz-lightyear-act-like-a-toy-around-people-in-toy-story) only furthers the theories.  Love questions like these.

Comment: Seems like the Army men think they are actual Army men.

Comment: @BamfTheNightAway I'm not really sure what is required to make them die, since stuff like Sid's toys exist.

Answer (score 31):

Because all the toys shown in [Toy Story](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toy_Story) are all old toys mostly. So they all know the reality. But [Buzz Lightyear](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buzz_Lightyear) is a new toy who doesn't know about reality. If you have seen [Toy Story 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toy_Story_2) then you will definitely remember that when new Buzz appears he is not under the impression that he is a toy. Even Zurg who comes later and tries to kill Buzz because he also doesn't believe that he is a toy rather thinks that Buzz is his enemy.

In short Buzz is not the only toy who doesn't know that he is a toy and mostly every new toy come to this phase that he feels he is a real person and not a toy.

Comment: Not to mention, the green aliens living inside the skill tester worship "the claw" as they see it as a divine entity taking them to a 'better place'. How would they know any different until they left?

Comment: I'm not sure that "mostly every new toy" feels this way, because the rest of Andy's toys seem *shocked* that Buzz doesn't know. If this were a normal part of toyhood, they would be expecting it, and know how to handle it better.

Comment: What if it's just that the company which manufactures Zurg and Buzz uses a different "process," (or whatever you want to call this...) so their toys don't know they're real?

Comment: @Kevin: That would mean that all companies, while having different manufacturing processes, **all** end up making toys that are alive unintentionally; yet they very specifically influence some of their beliefs? That seems unlikely. Most likely, all toys are inherently alive, regardless of their manufacturing process. Even Sid's "frankensteined" toys are still very much alive even though they are sometimes nothing more than a collage of different parts. It makes more sense if all toys are alive because of their child's imagination. Most toys seem to adhere to how their child thinks of them.

Comment: @Kevin: To explain a bit better; if toys come to life because of their child's imagination; then it stands to reason that their _initial_ state of mind is exactly what the child thinks about them. If Andy believes Buzz is real, so does Buzz. It is only _while alive_ that the toy manages to learn self awareness and starts creating its own identity.

Comment: But in *Toy Story 2*, when Buzz hid himself between other Buzzes all of them were speaking to each other while they knew they are inside a package.

Comment: @EtackSxchange they might have stayed in the store enough to get self ware.

Answer (score 5):

If a toy is new, they may not yet know that they are toys. Maybe that is the reason buzz didn't believe he was a toy. That was the character / personality of Buzz, that was also responsible for his reluctance to believe.
Its just an interpretation though!